# If the family of functions $H$ is relatively compact in $C[K]$, then it is also relatively compact in $L^p(K)$ for all $p \in [1,\infty]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am working through the book Fundamentals of Applied Functional Analysis, and in the chapter where the Ascoli-Arzela theorem is introduced, the question is asked: show that if the family of functions $H$ is relatively compact in $C[K]$, then it is also relatively compact in $L^p(K)$ for all $p \in [1,\infty]$. How would I prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a sequence in $H$, find a $C(K)$-convergent subsequence. Then it is an $L^\infty(K)$ convergent subsequence. (The two norms are the same for continuous functions.) Since $K$ has finite measure, convergence in $L^q(K)$ implies convergence in $L^p(K)$ whenever $q>p$. Hence the subsequence converges in $L^p(K)$ for $p \in [1,\infty]$.

Comment: Oh, I meant to type $[1,\infty]$, not $[0,\infty]$... sorry. So, this works for my original question, but I also accidentally typed $C[0,1]$ when I just meant $C[0,1]$... does this still work in that situation? (Sorry for all the mistakes!)

Comment: @user246984 Sure, just uniform convergence is enough.